# Vs 2010 Sql DB Project fails in x64

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

Tried to create a SQL 2005 DB project. In Vs, New Project >> Sql Server 2005 Database project. I right click the project in solution explorer. I get this error message:

An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close the window and try again.
Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "obj\Debug|Any CPU\HspDbTest.dbschema". Illegal characters in path.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets

If I try to build, it crashes VS. Just before it crashes, it shows a similar error messages in the build output. Note: I created an empty db project...it has not even imported anything from a db yet.

This is my configuration:
Windows 7 x64, VS 2010 Ultimate

I checked two other pcs with windows 7 x64, same issue.
I then checked a 32 bit win 7 and the problem doesn't arise.
I then checked an XP 32 bit and again, no problem.

I'm guessing this is a x64 issue with paths. Has anyone else run into this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a bug and I've submitted a bug on connect (please vote):
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/600315/vs-2010-sql-db-project-fails-in-x64

Meanwhile, I've found a workaround. I opened up the .dbproj MSBuild file and under , I added the following:
x86

That forces it to use the x86 stuff and runs fine. Hope that helps someone in the future.